# Creating and invoking an anonymous function in a single statement

Tags: php, closures, iife

A php closure or anonymous function is used to create function without specifying its name.

Is it possible to call them without assigning to identifier as we do in JavaScript ?
e.g.

```
(function(){
    echo('anonymous function');
})();
```

What is the correct use of `use` construct while defining anonymous function and what is the status of anonymous function in public method with accessibility to private properties?

```
$anon_func = 
function($my_param) use($this->object_property){ //use of $this is erroneous here
    echo('anonymous function');
};
```

Comment: A closure is not entirely synonymous with an anonymous function, although anonymous functions in PHP are of type `Closure`. Just so you know.

Comment: What is the exact error when you try your second code example? 'erroneous' is a little unspecific.

Comment: Cannot use $this as lexical variable

Comment: OP: I've updated my answer due to changes in PHP 5.4; don't ask me why they did it. cc @BoltClock

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible to call them without
>   assigning to identifier as we do in
>   JavaScript ? e.g.

Not in PHP 5.x; unless you count it when your method takes a callback as an argument. eg:

```
$square = array_map(function ($v) { return $v*$v; }, $array);
```

> What is the correct use of use
>   construct while defining anonymous
>   function

The `use` keyword indicates which variables from the current lexical scope should be imported into the closure. You can even pass them by reference and change the variable being passed, eg:

```
$total = 0;
array_walk($array, function ($v) use (&$total) { $total += $v; });
// $total is now the sum of elements in $array
```

---

> what is the status of anonymous
>   function in public method with
>   accessibility to private properties?

Closures defined inside a class have full access to all its properties and methods, including private ones with no need to import `$this` through the keyword `use` in [PHP 5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php):

```
// this works fine in PHP 5.4
$anon_func = 
function($my_param) { 
    $thing = $my_param + $this->object_property;
    echo('anonymous function');
};
```

Note that for some strange reason support for `$this` in closures [was removed in PHP 5.3](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures/removal-of-this). In this version, you can work around this restriction using something like:

```
// a workaround for PHP 5.3
$temp = $this;

$anon_func = 
function($my_param) use ($temp) { 
    $thing = $my_param + $temp->object_property;
    echo('anonymous function');
};
```

But this gives you access to public members only, attempting to access private members will still give you an error.

Also note that attempting to import `$this` (via `use`), regardless of the PHP version, will result in a fatal error `Cannot use $this as lexical variable`.

Comment: +1 It is not possible to self-invoke anonymous functions like `(function() {})();` in PHP though, probably for the same reasons array dereferencing isn't yet doable either as Marc B notes.

Comment: @BoltClock BTW array dereferrencing  (eg: `function foo() { return $someArray; }`, `$var = foo()['bar']`) works in PHP 5.4 as well

Answer (score 27):

PHP 7 added the ability to do this.

This code:

```
(function() { echo "This works as expected in PHP 7.\n"; })();
```

works as one would expect in PHP 7. (It still doesn't work in any PHP 5.x. release)

Answer (score 20):

```
call_user_func(function() use(closure-vars){ ... });
```

Comment: How would the OP make class properties accessible to the closure?

Comment: The op could create a reference of the object to pass to the closure through the use statement, ie: $obj = $this; call_user_func(function() use ($obj){}). That way he's have access to class properties and methods inside the closure. Bit of a hack but it's the best we have until PHP 5.4 arrives.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like it, as they still have to be declared with the `function() {}` notation, and on my 5.3.2 install, trying your sample notion returns an `unexpected '('` syntax error. The [doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) on closures doesn't mention it either.

Maybe it'll become possible once they patch up the parser to allow `somefunction()[2]` array dereferencing.

Comment: Array dereferencing has been added to [PHP 5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), but you still can't call anonymous functions right after their declaration.

Answer (score -1):

example 1

```
(new class {
    function __invoke($n) {
        echo "in PHP 7.\n";
    }
})(0);
```

example 2

```
(function() { echo "in PHP 7.\n"; })();
```

example 3

```
call_user_func(function() { echo "in php> 5.6\n"; });
```