# PHP static anonymous call doesn't work

Tags: php, lambda, static, anonymous

PHP 5.6, Apache 2.4 | Windows 7, OpenServer

```
(static function () {
    return true;
})();
```

Why this throws syntax error?

```
syntax error, unexpected '('
```

But http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php
PS: Also ->call doesn't work too... (unexpected '->')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem. It's not the static part that's not working:

```
$f = static function () { return true; }; $f(); //Works in PHP 5.4+
```

It's the declaring and calling that doesn't work:

```
(static function () { return true; })(); //Works in PHP 7+
```

Problem is the documentation is saying that the first syntax is valid in PHP 5.4+ but uses examples that require PHP 7+ to work.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work in PHP 5.x

You'll need PHP 7+ to run it.

Read more about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605701/372172

Comment: Odd how the manual seems to imply that it should also work in 5.4+